# Scala, ZIO, ZStream - how to stream custom data object to endpoint?

Tags: scala, zio, tapir, zio-streams

I want to stream data from `Zstream` with some repeat time. I have my main function which returns `ZIO`:

```
def processData(request: MyRequest): Task[Seq[SomePayload]]
```

I also call this method for every element in my list `requests`.

Now I would like to take this output and stream jsons I have in `Seq[SomePayload]`. I created a stream with endpoint:

```
  val streamingServerEndpoint: ZServerEndpoint[Any, ZioStreams] = streamingEndpoint.zServerLogic { _ =>
    val stream  =
      ZStream.fromZIO(ZIO.collectAll(requests.collect(service.processData(_))).repeat(Schedule.minuteOfHour(30))).map(_.toByte)

    ZIO.succeed((100L, stream))
  }
```

Endpoint:

```
  val streamingEndpoint: PublicEndpoint[Unit, Unit, (Long, Stream[Throwable, Byte]), ZioStreams] =
    endpoint.get
      .in("receive")
      .out(header[Long](HeaderNames.ContentLength))
      .out(streamTextBody(ZioStreams)(CodecFormat.TextPlain(), Some(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)))
```

But when I run this code, I can make a request to `/receive` endpoint but nothing is streamed in output. In logs I see `processData` method works and it returns data, but nothing on endpoint. How should I change this code to stream jsons (or jsons as bytes) on API?
I want also to run `processData` for all requests, every hour (minut of 30 every hour).

Comment: Not sure if related but Content-Length should be computed by the server or actually left empty for infinite streaming. Also your scheduling of 30 minutes might be a typo?

Comment: I want to repeat my `processData` every hour and stream body to output

Comment: Can you also show output of `curl -v` maybe?

Comment: Note that of you don't send any data for long period (several minutes), clients will likely close the HTTP connection.

Comment: It's nothing. Postman shows "sending request" and return no response. In app logs I see output from `processData ` method, so I think it is returned, but not on endpoint.

Comment: I'd also remove the content-length. This might confuse the server. Which interpreter are you using?

Comment: `curl -v` would give interesting details like responde headers. Please show us that.